# Various items in a buffer

Tags: qgis, buffer

New to QGIS and really all things GIS.

I'm looking at specific types of attacks in a region. Surrounding these attacks are other points like schools, clinics, political buildings, etc. I'm trying to identify what is in each of the buffers (a radius around the attack location).

I'm able to do it for each variable but would rather do it as a whole for everything, i.e. across the 23 attacks, what important sites are within a 10km radius of each attack?

Comment: That's an interesting context but what *actual* feature data do you have? Do you have a shapefile of your attack points? Is each attack a single point in a shapefile? Do you have feature data of your features of interest as points or polygons? Are they all in the same shapefile?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Michael. All the attack data was in a text delimited file and now in a shapefile with data to include the group conducting the attack, date, target, etc... and lat/long. The same is true with the other data that I'm interested in counting. They all come from separate text delimited files and were brought in independently to form the various layers. Does that help?.

Comment: Rereading your comment, yes each attack is a single point in a shapefile. Feature data are points save for another data set coming my way soon which represents territorial control by certain extremist groups.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: As you're after summary info: *for all attacks find all public buildings within 10km of the attack locations*, buffer the points to polygons and dissolve then use vector tools overlay intersect (or clip) to extract from all your public points the ones within 10km of all attacks.. the only curly bit is that your data is probably in geographic, project your data to an appropriate UTM projection before buffering and the rest should just flow.. which UTM projection depends on your rough location - name a country or supply an approximate median coordinate to limit the choices.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.